# Good, modern books on aerodynamics

Tags: resource-recommendations, aerodynamics

I graduated in Aerospace Engineering years ago, and I work in a completely different sector now. However, I would like to get a modern book on the topic and see how it's taught today. I understand that probably not much has changed in aerodynamics as a discipline, however, the way it's taught now may be different. The book I used during my bachelor was

https://www.textbooks.com/Fundamentals-of-Aerodynamics-2nd-Edition/9780070016798/John-D-Anderson.php

I could just get the latest edition, but maybe there are more recent books now.

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across this book from Mrinal Kaushik, Theoretical and Experimental Aerodynamics, Springer, 2019. It is for complete newcomers as well as graduate and covers nearly all aspects much more than Anderson with exercises and solutions. Furthermore has some Matlab examples, I think it's very important today to cover that, as it gives you a real touch of applied, practical physics.

Comment: Very nice, thanks. Code in Python would have been more valuable  but it's still a great suggestion. +1

Comment: The closest I know is the following Rubin H. Landau, Manuel Jose Paez, Computational Problems for Physics With Guided Solutions Using Python, CRC Press, 2018

Comment: For Astrophysics and Astronomy there is another one, I know off using Python, if you are interest let me know.

Answer (score 0):

if you have such a regard for aeronautics perhaps you would be interested in this book by "The Principles of Aircraft Engineering" by Michael H Tooley, and the paper "A History Of Aerodynamics" I hope this comes helpful I too like the field that you conduct studies in!

Comment: Here is the website address: https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_History_of_Aerodynamics/GzVIBAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0