# Good, modern book on compressible fluid dynamics

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations

I just asked a similar question for aerodynamics:

[Good, modern books on aerodynamics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/673497/118769)

I chose to ask a separate question, because aerodynamics and compressible fluid dynamics, while definitely related topics, are not the same thing. If you think I should ask a single question for both topics, let me know and I'll delete one of the questions.

I graduated in Aerospace Engineering years ago, and I work in a completely different sector now. However, I would like to get a modern book on compressible fluid dynamics adn see how the topic is taught today. I got this book during my Ph.D., which I liked a lot:

https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781441923356

It has a new edition, which seems interesting, but maybe other books came out in meantime which you would prefer to recommend.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/71257/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic you're clearly wrong. The two questions **are not the same**, as obvious by the fact that two of the recommended books don't even cover _compressible_ fluid dynamics!

Comment: @Qmechanic I was wrong, Chorin & Marsden cover compressible fluid flow (not in much detail) but Landau and Lifschitz do. I'll have a look at their book.